# Enable table view tr on checkbox check

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I am working on a project with tables. This is how my current table looks like (Not sure if I should paste the whole code, but here you are):

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<h2>HTML Table</h2>
<form>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Enable</th>
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
      <th>Column 3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>Row 1 1</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="nameid[]"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="tdd[]"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="active[]" value="TRUE"></td>
      <td>Row 2 1</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="nameid[]"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="tdd[]"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="active[]" value="TRUE"></td>
      <td>Row 3 1</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="nameid[]"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="tdd[]"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="active[]" value="TRUE"></td>
      <td>Row 4 1</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="nameid[]"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="tdd[]"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <button id="submit" class="button">Proceed</button>
</form>
```

Is there any possible way to disable all the lines (except the top one), and enable each line if the checkbox is checked?

Comment: "*Not sure if I should paste the whole code*" - only post the minimal amount - "*[mcve]*" -  of code necessary to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Take look at this https://jsfiddle.net/ddan/1rhrco48/

Comment: Well, if the entire row table is hidden, the cell containing the checkbox will be hidden too therefore you would not have any way to select it to make the row visible. What you can do is hiding only the 2nd, 3rd, and 4th cells of each row. As a side note, please notice that tables should be used only to display tabular data, not to manage the page layout; I strongly advise you change approach and use CSS in order to properly align elements.

Comment: @MarwenJaffel Very nice! Can the rows be disabled by default, and enabled on check?

Comment: By default the rows was disabled

Comment: By disabled do you mean still visible but the user not able to enter anything in the input boxes? (I can understand they’d still need to be able to click the checkboxes). And if they click a row does that mean you want anything they’ve already input in that row to be cleared?

Comment: *By disabled do you mean still visible but the user not able to enter anything in the input boxes?* Yes, that is correct. Only able to write in input text if the checkbox is checked. And all checkboxes should be unchecked by default, and all rows disabled by default.

Answer (score 0):

you can do that via javascript. If you want to select/diselect checkboxes by only using css it won't work. You see, html itself has a lot of limitations you can't change many values once the code is loaded.
Try this:

1 - Insert a classname to the checkboxes you want to change on one click, if you don't
want to change the first one, just don't put it in it.

```
<tr>
  <td></td>
  <td>Row 1 1</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="nameid[]"></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="tdd[]"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox" name="active[]" value="TRUE" class="ismarked"></td>
  <td>Row 2 1</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="nameid[]"></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="tdd[]"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox" name="active[]" value="TRUE" class="ismarked"></td>
  <td>Row 3 1</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="nameid[]"></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="tdd[]"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox" name="active[]" value="TRUE" class="ismarked"></td>
  <td>Row 4 1</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="nameid[]"></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="tdd[]"></td>
</tr>
```

I just added the class **"ismarked"** inside each checkbox html tag.

2 - Do the javascript work, i see you named the checkboxes as "active[]" and setted their values to "true", this way may work with some javascript code as well but it will give you a lot more of work. Here, i will add a button to do this changing work but you can do it with any element you want, even with a checkbox if you will.
This one goes before the button that is already in the html code:

```
<button class="change">Change the checkboxes</button>
```

```js
var ismarked = false;
document.getElementsByClassName("change")[0].addEventListener("click",()=>{
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("ismarked").length;
  if(ismarked){
    for(i=0;i<elements;i++){
        document.getElementsByClassName("ismarked")[i].checked = false;
    }
    ismarked = false;
  }else{
    for(i=0;i<elements;i++){
        document.getElementsByClassName("ismarked")[i].checked = true;
    }
    ismarked = true;
  }
});
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<h2>HTML Table</h2>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Enable</th>
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
      <th>Column 3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>Row 1 1</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="nameid[]"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="tdd[]"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="active[]" value="TRUE" class="ismarked"></td>
      <td>Row 2 1</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="nameid[]"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="tdd[]"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="active[]" value="TRUE" class="ismarked"></td>
      <td>Row 3 1</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="nameid[]"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="tdd[]"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="active[]" value="TRUE" class="ismarked"></td>
      <td>Row 4 1</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="nameid[]"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="tdd[]"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <button class="change">Change the checkboxes</button>
  <button id="submit" class="button">Proceed</button>
```

If you want to change the trigger for selecting/deselecting the checkboxes just change the element in the second line of the javascript code.